# The Navigation Service does not work while I am handling form Validation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have used indicative validator to validate the form. The Validation works perfectly fine. However, the navigation stops working when its written inside try when all validation operations are performed.

```
state ={
         name:'',
         email:'',
         password:'',
         password_confirmation:'',
         error:{},
         userAllData:'',
         userData:''

        }
```

Have used async and provided the rules for the email and password, the datatype and format.

```
  registerUser = async (data) => {
    const rules = {

      email:'required|email',
      password:'required|string|min:5'
  }
```

Error Messages to be shown and axios API call.

```
  const messages = {

    required: (field) => `${field} is required.`,
    'email.email': ' The email is required. ',
    'password.min': 'Password is too short.',
 }



 try {

    await   validateAll(data, rules, messages)

    const response = await  axios.get('https://react-blog- 
    api.bahdcasts.com/api/auth/login', {

      email:data.email,
      password:data.password
  })

      this.setState({
        userData:response.data.data.user,
        userAllData:response.data.data
      })

      NavigationService.navigate('PublicHome')

      }

       catch(errors){
        const formattedErrors = {}

      if(errors.response && errors.response.status === 422){
          formattedErrors['email'] = errors.response.data['email'][0]
          this.setState({ error:formattedErrors, })

      }

      else{
           errors.forEach(error => formattedErrors[error.field] = error.message)

           this.setState({ error:formattedErrors })
       }
   } 
}
```

Inside render: I have the textfields of email and password with a button inside which I  am calling `this.registerUser(this.state)` on Press handler.

```
    <Button style={Styles.btn} 
        onPress={() => { this.registerUser(this.state) }}>
        <Text style={Styles.loginBtnText}>{'Login'.toUpperCase()}</Text>
   </Button>
```